# Get Jekyll Data Files inside Converter Plugin

Tags: ruby, plugins, jekyll, converters

I'm trying to write a custom Converters Plugin for Jekyll. To do this I'd need to be able to access the Jekyll data files, in the `_data` directory.

I can access to the config files like this:

```
def initialize(config)
    var1 = config['var1']
end
```

But I don't find a solution for data files.

So, can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit : As **context.registers[:site]** is not available in Converter plugins.
But you can use this dirty trick:

```
  def initialize(config)
    dir      = config['data_source']
    filePath = File.join(dir, 'links.yml')
    data     = SafeYAML.load_file(filePath)
  end
```

Comment: Your solution rocks... THX